# Merge [data-cleansing] into [data-cleaning]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Both tags [data-cleansing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleansing) and [data-cleaning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/data-cleaning) have similar number of posts, 175 and 133.

They both mean the same to me, I would prefer to keep data-cleaning.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, we should absolutely get rid of "data cleansing," which is 100% synonymous with "data cleaning."  "Cleaning" is the more popular term on this site, as well as in industry as far as I'm aware (despite that Wikipedia treats "Cleansing" first).

It's been a few months since you posted this question, but "data-cleaning" continues to be slightly more popular.  I enhanced the tag description just now to make it more clear (it used to be mostly about "tidy data" which is just one aspect of data cleaning).